# Create MPSImage from pre-allocated data pointer

Tags: objective-c, macos, pointers, conv-neural-network, metal

In the application I'm working on, there are chunks of pre-allocated memory that are filled with image data at one point. I need to wrap this data in an `MPSImage` to use it with Metal's MPS CNN filters.

From looking at the Docs it seems like there's no easy way to do this without copying the data into either the `MPSImage` or an `MTLTexture`.

Do you know of a way to achieve that with no-copy from pre-allocated pointers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can [allocate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlbuffer/1613852-newtexturewithdescriptor) an `MTLTexture` backed by an `MTLBuffer` created with [`bytesNoCopy` constructor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtldevice/1433382-newbufferwithbytesnocopy?language=objc). And then allocate an `MPSImage` from that `MTLTexture` with [`initWithTexture:featureChannels:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metalperformanceshaders/mpsimage/2097547-initwithtexture?language=objc).

Keep in mind though that in this case the texture won't be in an optimal layout for GPU access, so this is a memory vs performance trade off.

Also keep in mind that `bytesNoCopy` constructor takes virtual memory page boundary aligned addresses only, and the driver needs to make sure that that memory is resident when you submit a command buffer that uses that memory.

Comment: Will this work for ```Texture2DArray``` type ```MTLTexture```s? I've tried creating textures from ```MTLBuffer```s before but they refused that type of texture. My ```MPSImage```s will have >4 channels.

Comment: No, it has to be `type2D` for it to be allocated from buffer. You might want to just copy the data, that might not even be a bottleneck